# Which version (MAR, OEM, ...) of Windows 7 to install on a Mac

Tags: windows-7

I have just purchased a Mac and for some legacy software need to run Windows on it.

Ideally I'll run the system in VirtualBox or dual boot it if it's slow.

I need to purchase a version of Windows 7, but I am confused by MAR, OEM etc.

Which version do I need to purchase?

Comment: I would recommend Windows 7. That is very stable and is full function.

Comment: The only license applicable would be a retail license.  You cannot purchase "OEM" licenses, since they come with OEM hardware, and you don't have already have an license nor are you using a Windows OEM hardware

Answer (score 2):

Technically you supposed to be a full retail version of Windows, I would recommend either Windows 7 or Windows 10. Windows 7 is older abut very stable and common. Windows 10 is shaping up to be very good but it is still experiencing growing pains.

As @Moab stated MAR licenses are for Microsoft Authorized Refurbishes, which you don't sound like. An OEM license is for system builders and reseller, which does not sound like what your doing either. So a full retail is what your supposed to get.

All the license version are the same windows they are just marketed and priced differently and the support provided by Microsoft varies as well. OEM and MAR does not get ANY support from Microsoft but if you buy the retail version you can get some general basic support from Microsoft for free.